# this vba code take so much time to copy and paste

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy columns one sheet to another however it takes so much time to copy.

```
Dim lastrow, erow As Long

lastrow = Worksheets("sheet 2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    Worksheets("sheet 1").Cells(i, 1).Copy
    erow = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("sheet 1").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(erow + 1, 1)
    Worksheets("sheet 1").Cells(i, 3).Copy
    Worksheets("sheet 1").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(erow + 1, 3)
Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select
```

I have lots of data and i want to make the time short as much as much possible

Comment: Is there any reason you are copying rows one by one instead of copying the entire range at once?

Comment: What is your actual goal? Explain in a little word with your code.

Comment: Yes, as with the other comments, it kind of hard to understand what you're wanting to do, especially, when you do things like check the last row in Sheet 2 and then use that it in the loop to select data from Sheet 1.  Some further clarification will help the community understand.

Comment: hey thank you for your reply sorry with my wordings 
actually i am trying to copy two entire columns ( A and B column ) from sheet 2 and want to paste in sheet 1 ( A column in A2 cell  and B column in B2 cell)

Comment: @GetSome_ have you found your answer? If so, do not forget to accept an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long ' Note that in your original code, "As Long" only applied to erow: NOT to lastrow. You need to specify "As..." for each variable individually, otherwise the rest are "As Variant" by default

lastrow = Worksheets("sheet 2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim CopyColumn1 as Range, CopyColumn3 As Range
With Worksheets("sheet 1")
    Set CopyColumn1 = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastrow, 1))
    Set CopyColumn3 = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(lastrow, 3))
End With

With Worksheets("sheet2")
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastrow, 1)) = CopyColumn1
    .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(lastrow, 3)) = CopyColumn3
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Three things here you can improve on:

1. You can define larger ranges to copy, it is not necessary to copy and paste row by row
2. If you only need to copy and paste values, you're better off doing something along the lines of `Range(x).Value = Range(y).Value` which is the same as copying the values from Range y to Range x. Note that these ranges have to be the exact same size.
3. Always refer to both the workbook and worksheet with each Range object. If you omit these references, VBA instead will refer to the active workbook (unwanted).

```
Sub copypaste()
Dim LRow As Long

With Workbooks(REF)
    LRow = .Sheets("sheet2").Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row 'LRow of col D

    'I am not sure what the ranges are you want to copy and where you want to paste them to
    'these are two exemplifying ranges
    .Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:D" & LRow).Value = .Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:D" & LRow).Value    
End With

End Sub
```